# Energy change of two discs in both the compression and restitution phases of a collision between them.

Tags: mathematical-physics, classical-mechanics

A collision occurs between two discs $A$, of mass $0.4kg$, and $B$, of mass $0.8Kg$, moving in the same direction with speeds $6$ $m/s$ and $2$ $m/s$ respectively. Given that the coefficient of restitution is $0.5$, calculate the energy change of each disc in the compression and restitution phases of the collision.

ANS: $4.98J$ loss, $2.84J$ gain;
$1.42J$ loss, $1.96J$ gain

(Assuming the first 2 answers are for the compression phase and the last 2 for the restitution phase).

Answer (score 0):

In the compression phase:

Let the common speed at max compression be $z$.

By conservation of momentum:

$$(0.4 * 6) + (0.8 * 2) = (0.4 + 0.8)z$$

so $$z = 3\frac{1}{3}$$

Also the approach speed is $(6 - 2) m/s$ = $4 m/s$ and so the separation speed is $(0.5 * 4)$ = $2 m/s$.

(the separation speed is the approach speed multiplied by the coefficient of restitution).

So after the collision, disc $A$ is moving at $xm/s$ and the velocity of disc $B$ is $(x+2)m/s$ (the separation speed is also the speed of disc $B$ minus the speed of disc $A$ after the collision).

By the conservation of momentum:

$$ (0.6*6) + (0.8*2) = 0.4x + 0.8(x+2)$$

which gives $x=2m/s$ so disc $A$ is moving at $2m/s$ and the velocity of disc $B$ is $4m/s$ after the collision.

Now for the kinetic energies:

**Compression phase:**

Disc $A$: $$\frac{1}{2}*0.4*6^2 - \frac{1}{2}*0.4*z^2 = 4.98J$$ which is a loss of $KE$.

Disc $B$: $$\frac{1}{2}*0.8*z^2 - \frac{1}{2}*0.8*2^2 = 2.84J$$ which is a gain of $KE$ as $\frac{1}{2}*0.8*z^2$ is the $KE$ at maximum compression and $\frac{1}{2}*0.8*2^2$ is the $KE$ before the collision.

**Restitution phase:**

Disc $A$: $$\frac{1}{2}*0.4*z^2 - \frac{1}{2}*0.4*2^2 = 1.42J$$ which is a loss of $KE$.

Disc $B$: $$\frac{1}{2}*0.8*4^2 - \frac{1}{2}*0.8*z^2 = 1.96J$$ which is a gain of $KE$.